# Use Laptop as Second Monitor with Thunderbolt 3

Tags: thunderbolt

I have two laptops, one being work laptop with a mini HDMI output port and one being a personal laptop with a Thunderbolt 3 port. The work laptop does not allow wireless connectivity to my personal laptop due to security reason.

I am thinking of using mini HDMI for output from my work laptop and the Thunderbolt 3 for input for my personal laptop (Razer Blade 15). Is it possible to use the personal laptop as a second monitor this way so that I can extend the screen from my work laptop to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop as external monitor for desktop via DP/USB-C?](https://superuser.com/questions/1352845/laptop-as-external-monitor-for-desktop-via-dp-usb-c)

Comment: Thank you! It seems the answer is no for now. Hopefully technology will soon improve and we will get to see that it is possible one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have found a good way to do this. I have purchased a video capturing device called Live Gamer Bolt from AverMedia. Basically I have my work laptop export HDMI out to the device and the device, which is connected to my home laptop via thunderbolt channel, captures the HDMI in and displays it on my home laptop.

https://www.avermedia.com/us/product-detail/GC555

There are cheaper alternatives too but the framerate will not be as smooth.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, and also happy you remembered to come back here and share!  It's probably a pretty narrow use case, but it's interesting regardless.  Remember to self-accept your answer when the system lets you.  And again, thanks for the update!